# Micrometer Kafka Number events per minute

Tags: prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I need to calculate how many events Kafka Listener consumes per 1 min.

I not sure about operator and I try with `increase(spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count[1m]) / 60`

I also tried with `rate(spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count[1m]) * 60` but results are very different.

It is a good approach?

Comment: What metric `spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count` represents exactly?

Comment: And maybe you have `spring_kafka_listener_..._total`? If this is the case it should simpler.

Comment: There is a total time only that. 
@markalex there is only that info: 

"name": "spring.kafka.listener",
"description": "Kafka Listener Timer",
"baseUnit": "seconds",

Comment: Without documentation on this metric, or example of values it's hard to say something certainly. My best guess `increase(spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count[1m])` (without `/60`), but you'd better go to Prometheus' UI, select graph tab and some well known period of time, and experiment with your queries.

Comment: I think the increase shows me bigger values than I expected but to be honest I can't confirm which value is true.  I tried to use sum(avg_over_time(spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count[$__rate_interval])) by (applicaton, instance, result, exception)